# how to access a field from multiple object which is present in array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

i have an empty array called `$scope.mobData=[];`

using $http.get(..) i get 10 json object and pushed to the array successfully and each object have 7 data, but i need only two field in each object called brandCode and brandName which is available in all 10 object. but in my UI part i am not able to display my brand name and brand code data, here is my html code

```
<table >
            <thead>
              <th>BrandCode</th>
              <th>BrandName</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="mobData in mobDatas">
              <td>{{mobData[index].brandCode}}</td>
              <td>{{mobData[index].brandName}}</td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" class="button button-positive" ng-click="editMobData(mobData)">Edit</button>
                <button type="button" class="button button-assertive" ng-click="deleteMobData(mobData)">Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

when i use `{{mobData[o].brandCode}}` i am able to view the data but without using the mob[0] i am not able to view my data. and also i have tried this  `{{mobData.brandCode}}`  i am not able to view my data

Comment: can you provide your json object code

Comment: You don't need `[index]` in your expressions.

Comment: s without using it how am i suppose to tell the UI that from which object it should print the brandCode there are 10 object from which object it will print the mobData.brandCode

Comment: could you add `mobData` object here?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/p6zQcDbBkceP1SINtJ4B?p=preview

Comment: every object in my array will look like this

Comment: {
"brandKey": 7
"brandCode": "110"
"brandName": "NOKIA"
"brandStatus": null
"brandCreatedOn": 1455181756000
"brandCreatedBy": "dev team"
"brandModifiedOn": null
"brandModifiedBy": null
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mobData` is object and you are using it like collection by using indexer, you probably need to access properties directly. Also if your collection name is `mobData` then ng-repeat would be on `mobData`  but not `mobDatas`.

I have made live demo where I had the array of objects having fields brandCode and brandName. I used that array in $scope in ng-repeat to render table rows as you have in the question.

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/sujiweyupa/2/edit?html,js,output)**

```
<tr ng-repeat="mobDataObj in mobData">
       <td>{{mobDataObj.brandCode}}</td>
       <td>{{mobDataObj.brandName}}</td>
```

Note you have to set initial state of angular.

```
app = angular.module('aaa', []);
app.controller('ccc', function($scope) {
$scope.mobData = [{brandCode: 'brand code 1', brandName: 'Brand Name 1'},
                {brandCode: 'brand code 2', brandName: 'Brand Name 2'},
                {brandCode: 'brand code 3', brandName: 'Brand Name 3'}];

});
```

Comment: i tried this but not worked please check my updated question

Comment: Try with my updated answer, collection in ng-repeat is probably mobData not mobDatas

Comment: s i am not getting the value

Comment: Can you explain "s i am not getting the value"? you get value through  mob[0].brandCode?

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:

```
<td>{{mobData.brandCode}}</td>
<td>{{mobData.brandName}}</td>
```

You don't need `$index` because you already have `mobData` that is same as `mobDatas[$index]`

Comment: actually i tried in this way please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Your binding seems wrong, it should be like

```
{{mobData.brandCode}}
{{mobData.brandName}}
```

Comment: i tried but i am not able to view it  i think we should mention index of brandCode and brandName

Comment: can you post your json?

Comment: i have attached my plunknur in the comment please check it out

Comment: Apparently the call is not returning any data, the callbacks are never invoked